# ORACLE APEX COMPILATION FAILED ERROR

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
create or replace procedure "PROC_UPDATE_SALARY"
    (p_ename IN VARCHAR2, p_salary_increase IN VARCHAR2)
 is       

 begin
 v_new_salary   lab01_sample_emp.sal TYPE;

       UPDATE LAB01_SAMPLE_EMP
          SET SAL = SAL + p_salary_increase
        WHERE ENAME = p_ename
    RETURNING SAL INTO v_new_salary;

 commit;

 dbms_output.put_line('INCREASED SALARY FOR: ' || p_ename ||
     ' TO THE NEW AMOUNT OF: $ ' || to_char(v_new_salary));

 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

All variables need to be declared before the begin section.

I would also recommend changing the second parameter to a number. This will make your declaration clearer and avoids Oracle having to do an implicit conversion in the update statement at execution time.

```
create or replace procedure PROC_UPDATE_SALARY
   -- Use number data type to move data validation to the 
   -- procedure call and avoid implicit conversion.
   -- (p_ename IN VARCHAR2, p_salary_increase IN VARCHAR2)
   (p_ename IN VARCHAR2, p_salary_increase IN NUMBER)
is       
  -- Declaration section
  v_new_salary   lab01_sample_emp.sal%TYPE;
begin
  -- Execution section
  UPDATE LAB01_SAMPLE_EMP
     SET SAL = SAL + p_salary_increase 
   WHERE ENAME = p_ename
  RETURNING SAL INTO v_new_salary;

  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('INCREASED SALARY FOR: ' 
                       || p_ename 
                       || ' TO THE NEW AMOUNT OF: $ ' 
                       || to_char(v_new_salary));

end;
/
```